# Graphite storage schema not working

Tags: linux, monitoring, graphite

I have configured the following storage schema in Graphite `/etc/carbon/storage-schemas.conf` file with the assumption that it would allow me to keep data with 60s precision during 356 days. Although when I convert data back using Whisper-Fetch, I get 60s precision for only one week of data. Any idea if I need to set this up in another file or am I missing something?

Storage schema

```
[collectd]
retentions = 60s:365d

Whisper info
whisper-info memory-buffered.wsp
maxRetention: 31536000
xFilesFactor: 0.5
aggregationMethod: average
fileSize: 855412

Archive 0
retention: 86400
secondsPerPoint: 10
points: 8640
size: 103680
offset: 52

Archive 1
retention: 604800
secondsPerPoint: 60
points: 10080
size: 120960
offset: 103732

Archive 2
retention: 31536000
secondsPerPoint: 600
points: 52560
size: 630720
offset: 224692
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `whisper-info.py` output shows that it's not using the schema you claim. The most likely answer is that the Whisper file was created before changing the schema. In this case you need to either delete the file (and let it get created again) or use `whisper-resize.py` to apply the new schema.

Comment: Which file you mean I should delete?

Comment: First- you need to restart the carbon-cache service, if you have made any changes to the storage-schemas.conf file.  then Second:  obfuscurity / the reply is referring to the .wsp files in question here (ie the ones that OP claims are NOT showing the 60sec precision he is looking for)-  in this case it seems that file is:  memory-buffered.wsp  (so either delete that file, so that carbon/whisper will re-create it from scratch with the new storage-schemas.conf parameters), or you can use whisper-resize.py to change it in place.